# cygwin + tmux and multiple bash processes

Tags: bash, terminal, cygwin, tmux

I have cygwin and tmux installed.
Every time I run a terminal I also run tmux and then fire up weechat. When I have to leave, I just close the terminal window and tmux keeps running in background... All good so far.

The problem is, every time I open a terminal again and attach to tmux session, a new bash process gets spawned, so if I close my terminal and attach my tmux session multiple times, I get several bash processes in Task Manager.

Am I doing something wrong or is that just how it's supposed to work?
Thanks

**EDIT:
Detaching TMUX before closing Terminal Window fixes my issue.**

This is what I see when closing the terminal while TMUX is still attached: [image: warning]

Comment: tmux is a terminal multiplexer, it is not a command interpreter, I assume the behaviour is normal. Every time you run a new terminal, the terminal run a new copy of command interpreter as bash, csh, zsh ...